# ionic reload a page from another page/modal

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

**EDIT**

I noticed that the subscribe event must come first before and publish get called. But it will be silly to ask user to open `TabOut page` every time when app start.

---

I do not need to always reloading the `TabOut page`, so I need this event sort of method to do the job. Or else could've just call the reload on `ionViewDidEnter()`.

---

I have 2 Tabs and 1 modal. /TabIn, /TabOut, and /ModalIn.

The `Tabs page` serve as data listing which display the data from database on `ionViewDidLoad()`.

The `ModalIn page` serve as data entry for the user to key in and submit data. This page resides in the `TabIn page` and will get called when user clicked on each of the list of data.

After successfully submit the form in the `ModalIn page` I want to call refresh again on the `TabOut page` (no matter it has been loaded before or not). I tried using events publish it is not working. Below are my code.

**ModalIn .ts**

```
let headers: any = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }),
options: any = { "username": val, formValue },
url: any = "some_url_here";

this.http.post(url, options, headers)
.subscribe((data: any) => {

  if (data.status == 'success') {
    this.events.publish('shouldReloadData');
  } else {

  }
},
  (error: any) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

**TabOut .ts**

```
constructor(public events: Events) {
  events.subscribe('shouldReloadData', () => {
    // Reload the page here
    console.log("should reloadddd"); // <- This is not working
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `subscribe` with `this` keyword inside TabOut.ts.

```
constructor(public events: Events) {

  this.events.subscribe('shouldReloadData', () => {

  });
}
```